# Why is the sequence of the quoted line like that?

Tags: sentence-structure, sentence-choice

I was reading Maugham and came across this:

> I had not yet learnt *how contradictory is human nature*; I did not know how much pose there is in the sincere, how much baseness in the noble, nor how much goodness in the reprobate.

I wonder why the line in italic is not “how contradictory human nature is”?

Answer (score 1):

It’s a matter of style.  It has the same structure as the three other instances he gives of things he did not yet know. That makes the passage flow nicely, almost poetically.

Comment: So it is just for poetic purpose? But normally, in that quote, we would say ‘..how contradictory human nature  is’, am I right?

Comment: @Angyang You're right. It's very poetic style.

Comment: @gotube I feel really sad haha, it seems that I can never sense any poetic taste of a sentence.

Comment: I think some people believe it's ugly to end a sentence with a short word like "is". But this rule doesn't apply in everyday speech.

Comment: @Angyang Sensing the poetry of a language requires great familiarity with the normal language so you can notice the difference. It will come :)